# Visual Studio - Local Variable names incorrect

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, local-variables

I am creating a web application in Visual Studio 2017. I am using C# and JavaScript for my back/front end respectively.

I am using Internet Explorer as the browser when testing my web application as it allows me to add breakpoints to my javascript files so that I can debug them and receive exception errors.

I have noticed then when I'm debugging, the Local Variables section which is supposed to have a list of my variables just shows a list of what seems to be random letters instead of my variable names. Please see the photo below. It seems that the variables names are getting muddled up somewhere.

Is there any way to be able to get the program to display the correct variable / object names and there respective properties etc?

[Local Variables Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akcud.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it also happen to C# in your side, or just JS code?

Comment: @LukeO, If possible, you could share a simple sample using one drive, we will download and debug it in our side using the same sample. Of course, you could also visit the variable name in other watch window like Watch windows or others. View the result.

Answer (score 0):

After checking option of  "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)", we could debug JS code in VS, how it seems auto or local window does now work properly, I tested it in my machine also got similar variables like yours:
[image]

And I found the Auto windows does not support JavaScript code in VS:

[What variables appear in the Autos window?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows#bkmk_whatvariables)